# Como eu insiro elementos de um primeiro vetor em outro segundo vetor, em uma determinada posição dada pelo usuário? e ainda imprimir o passo a passo

Tags: array, c++, inserir, elementos

```
Entradas - Tam do 1 vetor:5/
Elementos do 1 vetor: 1 2 3 4 5 /
Elementos do 2 vetor: 6 7 8 9 10/
Pos a ser inserida: 1

Saida- 
6 1 7 8 9 10 /
6 2 1 7 8 9 10 /
6 3 2 1 7 8 9 10 /
6 4 3 2 1 7 8 9 10/ 
6 5 4 3 2 1 7 8 9 10
```

OBS: O tamanho do segundo vetor deverá ser o dobro do tamanho do primeiro vetor, porem o segundo vetor terá apenas metade do seu tamanho ocupado.

Estou um pouco perdido, por enquanto esse é meu código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){ 
  int tam1, tam2, pos;
  cin>>tam1;
  int vet1[tam1];
  for(int i=0; i<tam1; i++){
    cin>>vet1[i];
  }
  tam2=tam1*2;
  int  vet2[tam2],vetaux[tam2];
  for(int i=0; i<(tam2/2); i++){
    cin>>vet2[i];
    vetaux[i]=vet2[i];
  }
  cin>>pos;
  for(int i=0; i<tam2; i++){
    vet2[pos]=vet1[i];  
    vet2[pos+1]=vetaux[pos];
    cout<<vet2[i]<<" ";
    pos++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema que tu estás tendo com o teu código? Algum erro? talvez resultado inesperado (qual)?

Answer (score 0):

Não acho que você pode criar vetores com uma variável,acho que só com constantes ou você precisa alocar memoria dinamicamente para o vetor.
Usando new ou malloc.

Aqui está um código de exemplo usando vector que vai facilitar a operação de inserção e de alocação.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> vetor1;
    vector<int> vetor2;
    int tam1;
    cout<<"digite o tamanho do vetor 1: ";
    cin>>tam1;
    for(int i=0;i<tam1;i++){
        int aux;
        cout<<endl<<"digite o numero para a posicao "<<i<<" do primeiro vetor: ";
        cin>>aux;
        vetor1.push_back(aux);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<tam1;i++){
        int aux;
        cout<<endl<<"digite o numero para a posicao "<<i<<" do segundo vetor: ";
        cin>>aux;
        vetor2.push_back(aux);
    }
    cout<<"saida"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<tam1;i++){
        vetor2.insert(vetor2.begin()+1,vetor1[i]);
        for(int j=0;j<vetor2.size();j++){
            cout<<vetor2[j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

links que podem ajudar:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new[]/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/